# Error 2001 AUDIO_INPUT_LEVEL_TOO_LOW in Agora video Call

Tags: agora.io

Everything was working fine but After updating Agora to 3.1.2., once remote user joined the video call, After a few seconds, Video call disconnected and getting this error in the log
"type":"exception","code":2001,"msg":"AUDIO_INPUT_LEVEL_TOO_LOW"

Version info.
"ngx-agora": "2.0.1",
"agora-rtc-sdk": "3.1.2",
Angular 10.0.8

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue by the developer and the team is working on fixing it and is an open bug on the Agora IO Community Repo [here](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AgoraWebSDK-NG/issues/39).

*In the words of the developer:*

#### How to reproduce

If you create and publish your microphone audio track without any user interaction, the remote user may not hear you. In this case, the console will print some logs like SEND_AUDIO_BITRATE_TO_LOW and AUDIO_INPUT_LEVEL_TOO_LOW.

And once you interact with the webpage, the remote user will hear you.

#### Root cause

Agora Web SDK NG uses the AudioContext API to do some audio pre-processing by default. However, the AudioContext is restricted by the browser's autoplay policy. If user has not interacted with your webpage, the AudioContext will not run. So there is no audio data produced from the SDK's pre-processing module in this case.

#### How to avoid

> We will fix this issue in v4.0.2, and it will be released next month.

For now, we recommend that you should ensure that the user has interacted with the webpage before the audio track is published. For example, the user is required to click the accpet or confirm button to start a call.